# Crashlytics.log and Crashlytics.logException not working as expected

Tags: android, crashlytics

Some version information first: I am talking about the module `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0` and the Gradle plugin `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1`.

I was excited to learn that Crashlytics can also log caught exceptions as nonfatal issues. But this doesn't seem to work the way I hoped it would.

Firstly, `logException` doesn't seem to trigger anything until the app is restarted after a crash. This renders the feature of logging nonfatal issues (app caught the exception and kept on running!) pretty useless.

Secondly, if there are two or more exceptions logged via `logException` before a crash, the last one wins and the others vanish into the eternal void. This is what I have observed during my experiments.

So what am I missing? Is there a way to tell Crashlytics that a logged exception should be sent out right away? Is this the way Crashlytics is intended to work, or is the implementation flawed? As it stands now, `log` und `logException` aren't of much use.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything, Crashlytics wasn't really designed with that use case in mind, which is related more to analytics than to crash reporting. You could instead use [Answers](https://fabric.io/kits/android/answers/features) APIs, also part of the Fabric platform. Note however, that there is no guarantee the logs will be sent *right away*, there is some delay before they appear in the dashboard.